# request.html in local file gets status = 0

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest, mootools, cross-domain

I'm making a functional mockup using mootools,and in this prototype I have to load an html file via request.HTML, but as soon as I run the script, the call never reaches the onSuccess due to the state = 0.

The blame could be that the request is treated as a violation of the crossdomain.
So I was wondering if is out there a way to work it around?

this is the code I use for performing the request

```
    req = new Request.HTML({
        url: "detail.html",
        onFailure: function(a) { console.log("iFailed: " + a); },
        onSuccess: function(r3, rEls, rHTML, rJS) {
           console.log("It worked!!");            
        },
        onComplete: function() { console.log('completed'); }
  }).send();
```

as I run this it always goes into the onFailure and in the onComplete without hitting the onSuccess.

I need this to work with safari, because the mock shall work on an iphone/ipad/ipod.

thx a ton

Comment: `url: "./detail.html"`, perhaps? I tend to pass fully qualified URIs myself.

Answer (score 0):

in the end I managed it bu injecting an iframe via js, instead of populating the div via ajax.
it's kind of lame and it sucks a lot, but at least it work and it's good for prototyping purposes.